# How do terminal progress bars work without clearing the full screen?

Tags: terminal

I was wondering how the terminal progress bar scripts manage to keep editing the same printed line without issuing any clear commands or form feed`(\f)`characters. I ain't a very advanced user and by now all I know is that once you have shifted from one line to another, you can't really go back to a previous one and edit it.